# NLog - create log file at specific directory in linux

Tags: linux, logging, nlog

I've a .net core application on linux server.also in application i used nlog for logging. my application path on linux is `/var/www-ninja/html/finance.api.gurukul.ninja`. but with use of nlog i want to store logs in other linux directory. which is like `/var/log/api/ninja/finance`. so can I store logs in that directory. how can i do that ? for more details

nlog.production.config

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          autoReload="true"
          internalLogLevel="Info"
          internalLogFile="c:\temp\internal-nlog.txt">

        <extensions>
            <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
            <add assembly="NLog.Extensions.Logging"/>
            <add assembly="NLog"/>
        </extensions>

        <variable name="ExceptionLayout" value="${longdate} [${processid}] ${uppercase:${level}} ${logger:shortName=true} ${environment-user} ${local-ip} ${aspnet-request-url} ${aspnet-request-method} ${message}${exception:format=tostring,Stacktrace}"/>
        <variable name="CommonLayout" value="${longdate} [${processid}] ${uppercase:${level}} ${logger:shortName=true} ${environment-user} ${local-ip} ${message} "/>
        <variable name ="logDir" value="/var/log/api/ninja/finance" />
   
        <targets async="true">
            <target xsi:type="File" name="file"  layout="${CommonLayout}" fileName="${logDir}\log-${shortdate}.log" />
            <target name="fileAsException"
                    xsi:type="FilteringWrapper"
                    condition="length('${exception}')>0">
                <target xsi:type="File"
                        fileName="${logDir}\log-${shortdate}.log"
                        layout="${ExceptionLayout}" />
            </target>
        </targets>
        <rules>
            <logger name="*" writeTo="file,fileAsException"/>
            <logger name="Microsoft.*" maxlevel="Info" final="true" />
        </rules>
    </nlog>
```

Comment: Make sure to use Unix-path, so stop using backslash \ . Ex. instead of `${logDir}\log-${shortdate}.log` then it should be `${logDir}/log-${shortdate}.log`. If still having issues then try to activate the NLog InternalLogger and check the output https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging

Comment: yeah ,that was the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to use Unix-path, so stop using backslash \

Ex. instead of `${logDir}\log-${shortdate}.log` then it should be `${logDir}/log-${shortdate}.log`.

If still having issues then try to activate the NLog InternalLogger and check the output https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging